# nltk path in azure functions python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, nltk

I am tring to use nltk in one of my folder but it can't find it

what i try to use:

import nltk
nltk.data.path.append("nltk_data")

in a one of my files

The file tree:

- main_azure_folder:

  - share_code:

    - text_analysis.py
    - nltk_data

What is the current way to path it?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post the output of the program you are trying to run? I guess your program is text_analysis.py. You can run it by executing python3 text_analysis.py in a terminal (cmd, bash, terminal).

Comment: Is the answer I posted what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look of the below doc if you want to import custom extension in your function, it tells you how to import:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior

For example, if you want to import dog.py file, you can use it like this:

[image: folder structure]

```
from . import dog
```

If it is a folder, then the files in the folder in the current trigger folder cannot be used as the source of import(must be level with the trigger), like this:

[image]

In this situation, we need to use this(If you want to import something to a folder you created yourself, such as test folder, use this method as well):

```
from ..test import cat
```